# Как добавить вкладку на заданную позицию в JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, вкладки

Есть несколько вкладок JTabbedPane. Мне необходимо вставить новую на первую позицию. Как это сделать?

Пытался так, но не получилось:

```
tabbedPane.add("Название",scrollPanea, 0);
```

Вот так получилось, а как теперь переименовать? –

```
tabbedPane.add(scrollPanea, 0);
```

Comment: `tabbedPane.add("Название",scrollPanea, 0);`
как-то так пытался, но не дает

Comment: `tabbedPane.add(scrollPanea, 0);` Ну вот так получилось, а как теперь переименовать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20int)) с индексом и [setTitleAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTitleAt(int,%20java.lang.String))

```
tabbedPane.add(scrollPanea, 0); 
tabbedPane.setTitleAt(0, "Название");
```

Либо задайте название у дочернего компонента:

```
scrollPanea.setName("Название");
tabbedPane.add(scollPanea, 0);
```